# Spinal Alignment and the efficacy of Chiropractic BioPhysics (CBP)

Tags: injury, back, back-pain

For the past several months, my gym has been closed. I was going 4 times a week, always increasing the weight/reps, etc. I moved to a new city and got back to the gym, doing what I did before but with a little less weight.

I used to squat 200lbs (3x10) so I started off with just 135lbs. After two sets I felt some pain in my back. The pain got worse and persisted for two weeks. It felt like a subluxation of a rib, or thoracic vertebra, which I've previously experienced with some skateboarding injuries. Sometimes it hurt to breathe, felt like a rib was poking into my lung, etc.

I saw a chiropractor/spine doctor who took x-rays, did adjustments, icing, exercises, etc. and I'm feeling much better after a week of that, but the then chiropractor suggested that I go into his "spinal correction/ CBP program" — not for my mid back, but for my neck and lower back.

Basically, they show you places on your x-rays where your spine is not in the "ideal curve" and talk about ways to adjust it using traction machines/bands/gears/etc. I was open to the until they told me it was $6000 for 3-6 months of treatment. I ended up leaving and not proceeding with the treatment, but they left me with a warning about my spine's shape and warned not to lift heavy objects until I get it fixed.

The whole environment felt very "sales-driven" and the doctor made several claims about the spine being the core of all kinds of health issues, electrical signals not making it to organs and causing every health condition known to man, etc.

I don't think the problem was as severe as they claimed, and I am skeptical of their methods, but I want to be sure that I don't re-injure myself. **Besides starting small with less weight, practicing careful form, etc. Is there anything else I should do to ensure that my back does not get injured again?**

Comment: Aside from the $6000 program (oof) did the Chiropractor give you any corrective exercises to perform? I know mine did and they regularly ask if I still perform them.

Comment: @C.Lange unfortunately, no. That seemed to be "behind the paywall"

Comment: You're seeing an actual qualified spine specialist over a general chiropractor right? Not saying chiropractors are bad, but spine specialists have about 12+ years of medical training while chiropractors use a variety of hand movements and natural therapies. I would visit a specialist. Most curves in your spine, if they are not genetic can be treated with physical therapy